# Problem with TextractJson to read a meteo API

Tags: talend

I connect to on meteo API with tRest.
I extract one JSON whose content is stred isn the field named "String".
I try next to extract the content of the field "win_dir" with ExtractJson.
But each time, the result of textractJson is 0 row.
Here is my job and the details of my component tExtractJson :

[image]

Thanks for your help

Comment: Add a small example of the JSON to be parsed.

Answer (score 0):

You should save the complete JSON response as a JSON file on your machine. Then use Repository>Metadata>Json File to create an Input JSON metadata based on this file. Follow the steps to create your json metadata and use it to create a tExtractJsonFields component.
Also make sur that your tRESTClient component use "JSON" as Content-Type and accepted-type, and that "convert response to DOM" is unchecked in advanced parameters.